# How can we get this patent repaired (page 3 of 5)?

Tags: us2560198

Page 3 of this patent wasn't scanned properly, and only a small portion of the top of Page 3 shows.  How do we get this patent PDF repaired?

Google used to have a "Report Issue" tool on all their patents, but removed it for some reason a couple of years ago when they reformatted their patent webpages (making them less user-friendly for older patents).  That important reporting tool needs to be restored, even if only in abbreviated form.

Comment: Yes, I am referencing the actual patent as a large portion of the patent document is missing!  That's certainly referencing "the actual patent."  Or, perhaps you might want to use a different term for what you're referring to.  Is this space only for discussing the invention and not the patent document & verbiage.  Are there actually rules herein regarding what's allowed?  Regardless, I would hope folks who post here would be open-minded enough to allow a broad area of discussion, such as incomplete patent documents.  After all, "a mind is a terrible thing to close" (sic) is it not?

Comment: The rules for this site is [here on the help pages](http://patents.stackexchange.com/help) -- the site is not affiliated with google.  The sites main purpose is to discuss and help understand the process around patent processes.  It does not provide any direct connection to patent authorities or inventors, and cannot be used to report issues as such.  Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If the patent is published as a US patent, you should be able to go to http://www.uspto.gov/ and find the official version of the patent (the google website is not an official version).

**UPDATE:**

The USPTO offers image scans of older patents (US256198 is from 1948).  The USPTO scan of [US256198 found here](http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?PageNum=0&docid=02560198&IDKey=FCD38CDD44F0&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO1%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526d%3DPALL%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsrchnum.htm%2526r%3D1%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526s1%3D2560198.PN.%2526OS%3DPN%2F2560198%2526RS%3DPN%2F2560198) and it is clearly not scanned correctly.

You should contact the USPTO directly to obtain a copy of the original official patent if you need the full copy.